# Struggling with fittype; attempting to pass several inputs and solve for several coefficients

Tags: matlab

I have several vectors of data and I understand the physical relationship between them. This allows me to build the structure of a function, but I still need to tease out the value of several coefficients. (Example: I know a relationship is linear but I need a and b). My function is a bit specific, so this process involves first building the function with the fittype.

Here's some code which represents what I'm doing:

```
% Known variables

Veh_spd = [data]; % 67400x1 array
Amb_T = [data]; % 67400x1 array
Cat_T = [data]; % 67400x1 array
P_loss = [data]; % 67400x1 array
M_cat = [data]; % 1x1, just a constant
deriv_Cat = [data]; % 67400x1 array. This is the output or "z" variable of the relationship.

% Building fit function, clarifying which variables I will pass. Need MATLAB to solve for ah1_cat, ah2_cat, aa1_cat, and aa_2 while I supply the vectors above.

cat_fit = fittype('((ah1_cat*Veh_Spd + ah2_cat)*(Amb_T - Cat_T) + (aa1_cat*Cat_T + aa2)*(P_loss))/M_cat', 'problem', {'Veh_spd', 'Amb_T', 'Cat_T', 'P_Loss', 'M_cat'});

%Applying the fit, passing variables

fitted_cat = fit([Veh_Spd_t, Cat_t, P_Loss_t, M_cat], deriv_Cat, cat_fit);
```

Here are my errors from MATLAB:

> Error using fittype>iDeduceCoefficients (line 619) The independent
>   variable x does not appear in the equation expression. Use x in the
>   expression or indicate another variable as the independent variable.
>
> Error in fittype>iCreateCustomFittype (line 475)
>       obj = iDeduceCoefficients(obj);
>
> Error in fittype>iCreateFittype (line 351)
>       obj = iCreateCustomFittype( obj, varargin{:} );
>
> Error in fittype (line 328)
>                   obj = iCreateFittype( obj, varargin{:} );
>
> Error in Thermal_Network_Creation (line 39) cat_fit =
>   fittype('((ah1_cat*Veh_Spd + ah2_cat)*(Amb_T - Cat_T) + (aa1_cat*Cat_T
>   + aa2)*(P_loss))/M_cat', 'problem', {'Veh_spd', 'Amb_T', 'Cat_T', 'P_Loss', 'M_cat'});

What am I screwing up here?